# Ad Hoc Distribution

Tags: iphone, xcode, xcodebuild, adhoc, hackintosh

This is the error generated when i drag App file and Mobile Provision File into the iTunes and sync it.
The application '" was not installed on your iPhone "" because it is not signed".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the target inspector code signing section.  You need to "sign" your app with an appropriate provisioning file, one that was generated for Ad Hoc distribution.

Comment: I signed the app using Target Inspector Code Signing Section under Build tab.I selected the Provision File in the drop down both against both fields CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY & Any iPhone OS Device.I created Distribution Configuration too.I selected it at both the locations.
1. In the drop down of Large Gray button under section Active Configuration on top left of Xcode window.

2. In the Target Inspector of the app under Build tab . I selected Distribution in the drop down of Configuration.

I have also created Entitlements.plist and uncheck the check box, 'get-task-allow'. Still its giving error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to delete the existing version from iTunes and the device each time you deploy.